# MySQL Update Statement taking long time to update small table with 4 rows

Tags: mysql, database, sql, mariadb

I've got a ridiculously small table in MySQL that consists of four rows of data.  Updating this table is taking a long time, often upwards of 50 seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE log_CacheQueueEntity 
( ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, EntityName varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
, CodingKey varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
, IsLockedForInitialization tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
, InitLockPID varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (ID)
, UNIQUE KEY UNIQ_8396A7A382A8ABB5 (EntityName)
, UNIQUE KEY UNIQ_8396A7A395B09DD2 (CodingKey)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then we're running a simple update query...

```
UPDATE log_CacheQueueEntity 
SET IsLockedForInitialization = 1
, InitLockPID = '1700151964:6556429c27fac7.78065467' 
WHERE IsLockedForInitialization = 0 
AND InitLockPID IS NULL 
AND CodingKey = 'SECTION';
```

This update query can take anywhere between 40-75 seconds to run... with only four records in the table.  We have other tables with thousands or hundreds of thousands of records that run updates in milliseconds.

EXPLAIN doesn't seem to give us anything, either.  We're at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: Please USE (your-dbname); then post TEXT results of A) SELECT count(*) from information_schema.tables; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE log_CacheQueueEntity;  C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "log_CacheQueueEntity"; for analysis.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; for a clue related to your system's activities.

Answer (score 2):

50 seconds sounds like `lock_wait_timeout`.  This would imply that another connection has the row locked and is taking a long time.

Perhaps a mysqldump is running?  Or some big transaction?

Also, this composite index may help:

```
INDEX(IsLockedForInitialization, CodingKey)
```

(This opposite order would work just as well.)

Comment: An index will not make the update on a 4 row table any faster. It's more likely to make it slower but both with / without the index the only reason for ths to be taking so long is locking. The slow query log / general query log will confirm as will queries against the the information schema.